# Моргает экран по клику на кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт плавного скрола на `jQuery`. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, - когда нажимаю на кнопку немного дергает и мерцает экран перед скроллом.
 Кто-нибудь сталкивался ?

```js
$('.btn--scroll').click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#form-head').position().top
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="h2" id="form-head">Заявка</h2>

<a href="#form-head" class="btn btn--scroll">Заказать звонок</a>
```

Comment: А якорь на ссылке есть?

Comment: поставил сейчас, дергать перстал, но все равно мерцает очень неприятно(

Comment: Добавьте код вашей разметки

Comment: обмновил, можно смотреть

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того, чтобы избавиться от такого мерцания и дергания, нужно в обработчике отменить стандартное поведение ссылки, используя `.preventDefault()`:

```js
$('.btn--scroll-with-lag').click(function(e) { // с мерцанием
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#form-head').position().top
  }, 1000);
});

$('.btn--scroll-without-lag').click(function(e) { // без мерцания
  e.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#form-head').position().top
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 2000px;
}

#form-head {
  background: #f00;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#form-head" class="btn--scroll-with-lag">btn--scroll-with-lag</a>
<a href="#form-head" class="btn--scroll-without-lag">btn--scroll-without-lag</a>
<div id="form-head"></div>
```

Comment: то, что нужно) Благодарю )